# Checking type of service which is extended form lib service inside forRoot ()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a shared lib which has a forRoot:

**shared.module.ts**

```
export class SharedModule {
  public static forRoot(config: {svc: SharedAbstractService}): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule > {
    return {
          ngModule: SharedModule,
          providers: [
            {
              provide: 'configurationService',
              useExisting: config.svc
            }
          ]
        };
  }
}
```

it has a shared abstract service :

```
export abstract class SharedAbstractService {
   abstract name: string;
}
```

---

Now, when I extend this service in a client app. something like:

```
@Injectable()
export MyClientService extends SharedAbstractService{
   name = 'Samuel';
  //..... some code
}
```

and then inject it from client app module , such as :

```
imports: [
  //...
   SharedModule.forRoot({ svc : MyClientService })
  //.. other imports
]
```

I get

> error TS2739: Type 'typeof MyClientService' is missing the following properties from type 'SharedAbstractService': name

What should I do as a type check in **shared.module.ts** so that I can pass `MyClientService`  as argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Type<SharedAbstractService>` as below

```js
import { Type } from "@angular/core";


export class SharedModule {
  public static forRoot(config: {svc: Type<SharedAbstractService>}): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule > {
    return {
          ngModule: SharedModule,
          providers: [
            {
              provide: 'configurationService',
              useExisting: config.svc
            }
          ]
        };
  }
}
```